# Monitoring physical network traffic with a VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, wireshark

**How can I monitor the physical network's traffic through a virtual machine (VMWare or Virtual Box)?**

I'm running Wireshark in a Linux VM and I would like to monitor *all* the network traffic. However only packets to and from the VM appear in my Wireshark capture.

I understand that with VM networking the host OS acts like a switch and forwards only packets destined for the VM to the VM.

Surely there must be a way to force the host to send all packets to the VM?

Answer (score 1):

In virtualbox there is a bridged network option.

Through the context menu on the vm, go into settings then network and switch it from NAT to bridged adapter.

Allow promiscuous mode.

This should allow you to do what you want.