# Capture network traffic from physical devices in a Linux VM

Tags: hyper-v, tcpdump

I have a Linux VM hosted in a physical Windows PC in Hyper-V. The VM is using an external switch. There are a few more physical devices in the network. When I run tcpdump inside the VM, I can only see packets sent to/from the VM and nothing else (other than broadcast packets).

Is there any setting which will allow me to capture all network traffic in the VM?

Note:

This question is almost identical to [Monitoring physical network traffic with a VM](https://superuser.com/questions/831041/monitoring-physical-network-traffic-with-a-vm), the only difference is that I'm using Hyper-V instead of VirtualBox

Comment: The answer should be exactly the same for Hyper-V as for VirtualBox. Have you tried it?